# POWER BI how to add different tooltips for each column in table visualisation

Tags: powerbi, tooltip

I want to add in a table visualisation in POWER BI different Tooltips.

Each column of my table return sum(quantity) by date. I want to add the tooltips for each column to show details of the quantity. Taking into consideration the date of the current column.

Can you please help me? Thank you

Comment: I have searched and searched. At this stage, it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Have you been able t do this yet or found a work around?